# The model is updating, but not the UI

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, model, angularjs-ng-model

I am using the [ion-datetime-picker](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker) in my ionic project. Everything works fine when I debug it in web browser. When I run it on real device, I found a problem. The input text doesn't update. I check it with `chrome://inspect/#devices`, I see that the value of the input (model) changes even though the text in the input not changing.

I have added new issue [here](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker/issues/50), hopefully anybody here can help too. Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have tried to add a callback too in this plugin with ng-click, and pass the value accordingly to the scope and after that do some `triggerHandler` to the input.

```
    $scope.changeme = function(val) {
        alert(val)
    }
```

The strength is it alert the value three times. The first time it alert the full date description, the second time it alert with time format as expected like `13:30`, and finally the last time it only alert `Nan:Nan`

I also did $scope.$apply() and it still doesn't help.

Please help. I spent my whole night only for this thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add plunker or codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The plugin](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker) (made by me) is not meant to be used with `<input>` element. Why?

- It uses `ng-model` and it's modelValue-viewValue mechanism which is in conflict with `ng-model` mechanism of `input` element
- It uses `Date` instance as it's model, which is in conflict with plain string model of `input` element
- The directive marks element that, when tapped, would open the picker. Tapping input element already has it's own meaning - focusing it.

Use `<div ion-datetime-picker ng-model="x">{{x | someFilter}}</div>` or whatever fits your needs instead.

See [#25](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker/issues/25) and [#21](https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker/issues/21) for more info.